# Can we keep HTML, JS and CSS files separate while creating Vue.js components like in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Can we keep HTML, JS and CSS files separate while creating Vue.js components?
I've gone through ["Why Vue.js doesn't support templateURL"](https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/) article. The article itself says

> "Proper modularization is a necessity if you want to build anything
>   large and maintainable."

However, itself limits the possibility to modularize the code further. I'm coming from an Angular background and I feel separating HTML, JS and CSS is really helpful during development. However the author of the above article has a different opinion. However, this option should have been left up to the developer, so that at least during development he can separate HTML, JS and CSS if he's comfortable doing that.
Apart from modularity, doing the separation will help in being able to reuse these assets anywhere else. All this is lost with the existing opinion.

He also says,

> Well, maybe it’s time to up the game a bit and use a proper module bundler like Webpack or Browserify. It might seem daunting if you’ve never dealt with them before, but trust me it’s worth it to take the leap.

But what does it mean? Does it mean that this can be achieved if we use a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify? If yes, how?

Having said all that is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found this in the docs but not sure it's what you're looking for

```
<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template>
<div>This will be pre-compiled</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```

And [doc comment](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns)

> Even if you don’t like the idea of Single-File Components, you can
> still leverage its hot-reloading and pre-compilation features by
> separating your JavaScript and CSS into separate files

Comment: This definitely looks like the most proper approach in this scenario....which I was about to use until I read Mark Cooper's answer below.  I agree with him in the sense that trying to shoehorn practices from one framework into another is probably not the best approach.  For that reason, I'm going to do this first project "the Vue way".  Maybe after I've built a dozen or so of these, I'll have the experience with Vue to make judgement calls and also I'll know what (if anything) I'll be sacrificing by making such changes.

Comment: As an experience react and angular dev, I was iffy about Vue for this reason along, since even before react days, it was always considered a bad practice to have JS/HTML/CSS in the same file. thats why biggest React critism in earlier days was the same, all in JS.

i am so happy i can do this in Vue, because i was considering dropping vue.

Comment: From my point of view there is no only one single best approach. It depends if you want your application to die along with the framework/library or not. If I want my application to persist as long as possible across time, I would use from the framework/library the minimum possible so it can be easily migrated if needed. Let's face it frameworks/libraries change over time. If you do everything "the way of the framework" at some point if you want to migrate to another framework most probably you will have to rewrite everything from scratch. So keeping the css separated is good for this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO when you approach a new framework, you'll usually need to leave the conventions of other frameworks behind. For example, trying to shoehorn in an Angular *style* into a Vue project is likely to cause more pain, and limit the benefits of the new framework. This is the same for React, Aurelia, Ember etc. They all do things in their own way and it is best to follow their conventions for a number of reasons.

To answer your question: I didn't find a way to split the files which I agree would have been nice, for example;

```
- myfile.html.vue
- myfile.css.vue
- myfile.js.vue
```

My recent research of **Vue** found that combining related elements into a single ***.vue** file will give you benefits of encapsulation. But the trade off for good encapsulation is usually repetition. You'll need to decide whats the best pattern for you - *Don't repeat yourself* or *Single responsibility*?

I also found that I can use embedded Vue scripts and inline code for simple examples, but once I moved to ***.vue** files I then needed to consider a module bundler. Once this became apparent the *simplicity* of vue (which on the face of it is the main selling feature) was lost a little.

Comment: Apart from modularity, separating the HTML, JS and CSS will help in being able to reuse it anywhere else. All this is lost with the existing opinion.

Comment: I agree with you. If they could've provided with this ability to separate the assets it would've continued to be simple.

Comment: Disagree though on `the trade off for good encapsulation is usually repetition` and that DRY is a counter player for single responsibility. Those are not mutually exclusive things!!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there definitely comes a point where components can get really long and it is beneficial to split apart the HTML, CSS and JS for navigation purposes. The skeptics may point out that this is a sign that your component should be broken into smaller pieces, and maybe that's true, but whatever.

This is how you can do it.

Vue supports "mixins". This allows you to move almost all your JS into a mixin file and it will be inherited in to the component. The actual JS code left in your component file at that point is pretty minimal (just the ~4 lines defining the mixin).

You can then move the CSS into an external file that you use @import to pull in. I think you might lose the ability to use "scoped" though.

At this point, your component file contains 99% HTML only.

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly, I think that people that want single file components never actually wrote frontends for a line of business application. We have forms that can sometimes span 20-30 lines on screen, resulting in a html template of about 100 custom components.

Scrolling back and forth is hell for such components. I also don't really see a sensible way of cutting the form into subcomponents.

My workflow is having the javascript and the related view template side by side on one monitor, and my browser with the browser dev panel on the other monitor. That seems to work out nicely. I can't understand the pigheadededness of some people. I'm investigating Vue.js as an alternative to our current outdated CanJS implementation, but this is a major deterrent.